# How Facebook is redirecting to another website and from there posting an image in user timeline

Tags: facebook

While going through my friends posts in Facebook Application I have observed that some images with a question like "which characters suits to you in 'some movie name'  movie". whenever I click on that image it is redirecting me to their website(Ex:- Brochill) and asking me to login with Facebook credentials.

Once I do login successfully It is redirecting to a page where it is going to show me an image with a character name and image of the selected movie. whenever I click on post on my Facebook wall it is automatically redirecting to my Facebook application and posting that image automatically.

I wanted to know how exactly the internal functionality is working.

**My Observations:-**

- For the website which we are redirecting we need to login first.
  without login it will not work.
- It will create a same image whenever I tried to click on the image in the Facebook App It is giving me the old generated image. I think they are maintaining the user details with generated images.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Apps can not publish anything automatically any more on user profiles. At most they can show the user a dialog, to let them actively share a URL to their timeline.

Comment: @misorude, I wanted to know how to show the user dialog.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/web